# Change password daily based on a key

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption, c#-4.0

I want to add the ability to my program that when it starts up an engineer has to enter a password.

I was thinking that each engineer is give their own key and based on this key and a daily changing public key it will allow them access to the program.

The reason I am thinking this way is because there is a program that they might leave at a customer's site which needs to be protected.  If something is changing daily then the customer will not be able to access it even if they know a key on one day.

If there is some other approach I'm open to it thanks.

UPDATE: This program is a licence generator which enables/disables features for our main program .  Obviously if this gets left on site then we lose money possibly.

Comment: That's an option, but I missed the question part: Are you asking how to *implement* it?

Comment: I'm asking how to implement it or how to implement another approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What 'we' do is that we have a daily changing key that needs to be entered into the support program. Though the program can be left anywhere, engineers simply have access (for example on an USB stick) to generate these one-day keys. Variations on this are available.

These key generator tools can of course be keyed to individual personel.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Ah, you want to enable features in your program based on a key that can be changed during the program lifetime by an engineer/support assistant. You have several options. You have an encrypted license file in your 'main' software which determines features. The license generator, which you want to keep secure, you could implement as either web service which needs a login or perhaps a program on a USB key which requires a password. But with a daily changing password your engineers will still need contact with 'home'. So why not put your license tool online? It cannot be left behind then.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 2-factor key fob like this: http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156

Comment: We have something similar, the issue is the program writes to the fob and determines functionality in another program.  If they left the licence generator program on site the customer could enable more than they are entitled to

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just distribute the program on an USB stick and run from there or for some reason not possible? It would save you the trouble of thinking of a password, the usb stick contents code be encrypted so even if it is lost you are safe.